# How to properly access object's List<> value in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the object value but I don't know how to do it. I'm new to C# and its giving me syntax error. I want to print it separately via the method "PrintSample" How can I just concatenate or append the whatData variable . Thank you.

```
PrintSample(getData, "name");
PrintSample(getData, "phone");
PrintSample(getData, "address");


//Reading the CSV file and put it in the object
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("sampleData.csv");
            var list = new List<Sample>();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var values = line.Split(',');
                var sampleData = new Sample()
                {
                    name = values[0],
                    phone = values[1],
                    address = values[2]
                };
                list.Add(sampleData);

            }

 public class Sample
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string phone { get; set; }
            public string adress { get; set; }
        }
//Method to call to print the Data
 private static void PrintSample(Sample getData, string whatData)
        {
            //THis is where I'm having error, how can I just append the whatData to the x.?
            Console.WriteLine( $"{getData. + whatData}"); 
            
        }
```

Comment: What `x.` stands for?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake x is the "getData" parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using reflection. However, it's known to be relatively slow.

```
public static void PrintSample(object getData, string whatData)
{
    Console.WriteLine( $"{getData.GetType().GetProperty(whatData).GetValue(getData, null)}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# it's not possible to dynamically evaluate expression like

```cs
$"{getData. + whatData}"
```

As opposed to languages like JavaScript.

I'd suggest to use rather [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) or `Dictionary<string, string>`

```cs
public void PrintData(Sample sample, string whatData)
{
    var data = whatData switch
    {
        "name" => sample.name,
        "phone" => sample.phone,
        "address" => sample.address
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(whatData)),
    };
   Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What PO really needs is

```
private static void PrintSamples(List<Sample> samples)
{
foreach (var sample in samples)
Console.WriteLine($"name : {sample.name} phone: {sample.phone} address: {sample.address} ");
}
```

and code

```
 var list = new List<Sample>();
 foreach (var line in lines)
   {
     ......
     }
   PrintSamples(list);
```

it is radicolous to use

```
PrintSample(getData, "name");
```

instead of just

```
PrintSample(getData.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps this will help you:

```
private static void PrintSample(Sample getData, string whatData)
{
    var property = getData.GetType().GetProperty(whatData);
    string value = (string)property?.GetValue(getData) ?? "";
    Console.WriteLine($"{value}");
}
```